# Verify if user is wordpress logged in from another app since wordpress 4.0

Tags: plugin-development, login, security

I try to implement in my Node.js app a way to verify if the user cookie is valid. I've found some post in internet who explain me very well the things, but as i try to implement it, with the WordPress-auth module for Node.js, I've found that it's not working.

After some search, I've found from **WordPress 4.0** for some reason :

- Now, if the **logged_in cookie name is still hashed with MD5**, hashed salted password is now **sha256 (or sha1 if impossible) encrypted**, considering this part of code in WordPress function `wp_generate_auth_cookie()` :

  ```
  // If ext/hash is not present, compat.php's hash_hmac() does not support sha256.
  $algo = function_exists( 'hash' ) ? 'sha256' : 'sha1';
  $hash = hash_hmac( $algo, $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token, $key );
  ```
- I'm not sure but as i found in the code, since WordPress 4.0, the logged in salt isn't used anymore, but there is usage of token defined in WP_Session_Tokens, as below :

  ```
  $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
  $token   = $manager->create( $expiration );
  ```

So i want to know : **is there a way from wordpress 4.0 to verify logged_in cookie ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've found the solution.

In fact, as i haven't noticed, **there is always the hashed mdp**, but for now, the logged_in cookie is structured like this :

%login%|%timeout%|**%sessionId%**|%passhached%

instead of :

%login%|%timeout%|%passhached%

This is like this since wordpress 4.0, and the wp_session_cookie integration, the auth method is the same that before but there is just 2 change :

- **the sessionid is introduced** in the cookie and the key calculation
- the logged_in cookie encryption is **sha256 or if not possible sha1**

So there is a scheme of the encryption process

```
KEY = md5_HMAC(%login%|%caracter 8-12 of the passhached in database%|%timeout%|%sessionId% , LOGGED_IN_KEY.LOGGED_IN_SALT);

RESULT = sha256_HMAC(%login%|%timeout%|%sessionId% , KEY);
// RESULT = sha1_HMAC(%login%|%timeout%|%sessionId% , KEY); only if sha256 is not supported
```

And for now, to approve a connexion, the logged_in_cookie's pass hached need to be same as RESULT